# Is it safe to use next within a for loop in Python?

Tags: python

Consider the following Python code:

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a = iter(b)
for x in a :
    if (x % 2) == 0 :
        print(next(a))
```

Which will print 3, 5, and 7. Is the use of `next` on the variable being iterated on a reliable construct (you may assume that a StopIteration exception is not a concern or will be handled), or does the modification of the iterator being looped over inside the loop constitute a violation of some principle?

Comment: A question to ponder: what happens if you skip the `if` condition and always call `next(a)`?

Comment: That's fine as long as you know what you're getting into.

Comment: Ok, but worth commenting if others are going to be using/reading the code.

Comment: Other than academic interest, I fail to understand why one would write code like this?

Comment: @copper.hat You can see here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53762253/using-a-python-script-which-reads-a-77gb-file-into-memory-to-scan-for-keywords - for the motivating example. The aim is to find a line in a file too large to read into memory and process the next line. The `pairwise` recipe in timgeb's answer is a clearer way to do this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's nothing *wrong* here protocol-wise or in theory that would stop you from writing such code. An exhausted iterator `it` will throw `StopIteration` on every subsequent call to `it.__next__`, so the `for` loop technically won't mind if you exhaust the iterator with a `next`/`__next__` call in the loop body.

I advise against writing such code because the program will be very hard to reason about. If the scenario gets a little more complex than what you are showing here, at least I would have to go through some inputs with pen and paper and work out what's happening.

In fact, your code snippet possibly does not even behave like you think it behaves, assuming you want to print every number that is preceded by an even number.

```
>>> b = [1, 2, 4, 7, 8]                                              
>>> a = iter(b)                                                      
>>> for x in a: 
...:    if x%2 == 0: 
...:        print(next(a, 'stop'))                                   
4
stop
```

Why is `7` skipped although it's preceded by the even number `4`?

```
>>>> a = iter(b)                                                      
>>>> for x in a: 
...:     print('for loop assigned x={}'.format(x)) 
...:     if x%2 == 0: 
...:         nxt = next(a, 'stop') 
...:         print('if popped nxt={} from iterator'.format(nxt)) 
...:         print(nxt)
...:                                               
for loop assigned x=1
for loop assigned x=2
if popped nxt=4 from iterator
4
for loop assigned x=7
for loop assigned x=8
if popped nxt=stop from iterator
stop
```

Turns out `x = 4` is never assigned by the `for` loop because the explicit `next` call popped that element from the iterator before the `for` loop had a chance to look at the iterator again.

That's something I'd hate to work out the details of when reading code.

---

If you want to iterate over an iterable (including iterators) in "`(element, next_element)`" pairs, use the `pairwise` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from the `itertools` documentation.

```
from itertools import tee                                         

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..." 
    a, b = tee(iterable) 
    next(b, None) 
    return zip(a, b)
```

Demo:

```
>>> b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]                                               
>>> a = iter(b)                                                       
>>>                                                                   
>>> for x, nxt in pairwise(a): # pairwise(b) also works 
...:    print(x, nxt)                                                                      
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
```

In general, `itertools` together with its recipes provides many powerful abstractions for writing readable iteration-related code. Even more useful helpers can be found in the [`more_itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) module, including an implementation of [`pairwise`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.pairwise).

Comment: The example above is, of course, a toy, you can see the motivating example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53762253/using-a-python-script-which-reads-a-77gb-file-into-memory-to-scan-for-keywords where the asker wants to search for a particular sequence in one line and print the next.

Comment: @JackAidley Usually, in cases like these, I believe the pattern to `zip` the list with itself, offset by one is interesting. For instance, you could do : `for previous, current in zip(my_list, my_list[1:]):`. This prevents you from doing fancy tricks with `next`, and is quite readable and elegant.

Comment: @VincentSavard This doesn't work when reading lines from a file, however.

Comment: @JackAidley Why wouldn't it work? You can read the first two lines to create the first element, then it's just a matter of reading the file line by line.

Comment: @VincentSavard I think Jack means that you cannot slice the iterator over lines you get from opening a file. `pairwise` from the [`itertools` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) handles that.

Comment: @VincentSavard Because a file (well, a `_io.TextIOWrapper`) cannot be subscripted, so if you do `with open("afile.txt", "r") as file:` you cannot then take `file[1:]` as the second parameter to `zip`.

Comment: @JackAidley Of course, it was an example so you could understand the pattern. You can obviously do the same thing without subscripting.

Comment: I recommend giving some more emphasis to `more_itertools`. Maybe show an example of using it directly, or maybe reorganize the answer so it's the main solution and offer the custom implementation if including packages is a problem. +1 for an excellent answer. It's *always* simpler if you can eliminate two iterations of a loop interacting with each other.

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you mean by 'safe', as others have commented, it is okay, but you can imagine some contrived situations that might catch you out, for example consider this code snippet:

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a = iter(b)
def yield_stuff():
    for item in a:
        print(item)
        print(next(a))
    yield 1

list(yield_stuff())
```

On Python <= 3.6 it runs and outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

But on Python 3.7 it raises `RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration`. Of course this is expected if you read [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) and if you're thinking about handling `StopIteration` anyway you might never encounter it, but I guess the use cases for calling `next()` inside a `for` loop are rare and there are normally clearer ways of re-factoring the code.

Comment: Nice catch on a subtle difference between versions.

Answer (score 4):

If you modify you code to see what happens to iterator `a`:

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a = iter(b)

for x in a :
    print 'x', x
    if (x % 2) == 0 :
        print 'a', next(a)
```

You will see the printout:

```
x 1
x 2
a 3
x 4
a 5
x 6
a 7
```

It means that when you are doing `next(a)` you are moving forward your iterator. If you need (or will need in the future) to do something else with iterator *a*, you will have problems. For complete safety use various recipes from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module. For example:

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b) 

b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a = iter(b)
c = pairwise(a)

for x, next_x in c:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print next_x
```

Not that here you have full control in any place of the cycle either on current iterator element, or next one.